# Refresh data from table without rebuilding project in adf 12c

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, adfs2.0, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have created a fusion web app in adf 12c and using 12c database.
After building my application, I accidentally delete some rows in table but didn't press commit button. The deleted rows are not showing there but present in database(checked after refresh). I want to refresh data from database either on page refresh/reload or through some command button. How can i do that without rebuilding my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is **how to implement a rollback on an ADF table?**

- Go to your **Datacontrols** panel
- Open the **application module** where the View Object of your binded RichTable originate
- Go to the **Operation** folder
- Drag and drop the **rollback operation** as an **ADF command button** to your JSF page

it will look like this :

```
 <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Rollback.execute}" text="Rollback" disabled="#{!bindings.Rollback.enabled}" immediate="true" id="cb6">
```

You can also do it in Java :

```
 appModule.getTransaction.rollback();
```

This rollback operation will cancel all the modification done to the application module and query the database again for all his View Object.

Read more here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14022/oracle/jbo/ApplicationModule.html

> **Transaction**
>
> Associated with the root Application Module is the Transaction object,
>   which provides this transaction context. From any (root or nested)
>   Application Module, the user can retrieve the transaction object
>   through a call to getTransaction(). In reality, getTransaction() first
>   locates the root Application Module and then returns the transaction
>   object from it.
>
> The Transaction object manages connection to database and Entity
>   caches. Thus, changes made through one View Object are visible to
>   other View Objects as long as these View Objects all parented by the
>   one root Application Module. In contrast, if two View Objects are
>   parented by two separate root Application Modules, then changes made
>   through the View Object will not be seen by the second View Object
>   until the changes are committed to database through the first root
>   Application Module and the second VO executes query (to retrieve the
>   most up-to-date data from database).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick up the executeQuery operation for the View Object that populates your table and drop it on your page as a button. Pressing the button will re-query your DB to fetch the data from there.